# Doit-on accorder le premier participe passé employé avec l’auxiliaire avoir dans la phrase citée dans le corps de la question?

Tags: accord, participe-passé, en

> J’ai eu des problèmes gastriques durant la diffusion du *Bye Bye 2022*, ce qui fait que je n’en ai **vu(e)** qu’une partie que, par ailleurs,  je n’ai pas trouvée si drôle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **LBU § 942** Règle générale.
> Le participe passé conjugué avec *avoir* s'accorde en genre et en
> nombre avec son objet direct quand cet objet le précède ; — il ne
> varie pas (ce qui est le cas le plus fréquent) s'il est suivi de son objet
> direct ou s'il n'a pas d'objet direct.
>
> Il varie :
> • Les efforts que nous avons FAITS.
> •  Ces conséquences, je les avais PRÉVUES.
> • Ils étaient coupables : on les a PUNIS.
> • Les gentilles qualités qu'il avait EUES *Bébert* (CÉLINE,
> Voy. au bout de la nuit, F°, p. 441).
> •  La porte que quelqu'un a OUVERTE / La porte que
> quelqu'un a REFERMÉE / [...] / La lettre que quelqu'un a LUE. / La chaise que quelqu'un a
> RENVERSÉE (PRÉVERT, Paroles, Message).
> • Cest surtout les bêtises humaines qu'a PEINTES Flaubert (FAGUET, cit. Sandfeld, t. II, p. 126).
> • Quels efforts avez-vous FAITS ?
>
> Il ne varie pas :
> • Nous avons FAIT des efforts.
> • J'avais PRÉVU ces conséquences.
> • On a PUNI les coupables.
> • Elles ont toujours ESPÉRÉ
> • jamais elles n'ont DOUTÉ du succès.

- J’ai eu des problèmes gastriques durant la diffusion du *Bye Bye 2022*, ce qui fait que je n’en ai vu(e) qu’une partie que, par ailleurs, je n’ai pas trouvée si drôle.

Ce qui a été vu, c'est une partie (de la diffusion, « en ») : comme « partie » est placé après le verbe il n'y a pas d'accord : « je n’en ai vu qu’une partie ».